# Read multiple HTML-Tables to CSV/Excel with POST-Login

Tags: php, csv

We have some Web System from our Partner, which does not have an export-file function. But we need them for our tax-office.

What I want to build:

Open a given URL, Login via POST-Form to the System, grab the Table from the ""-Tag copy it to an variable, count a variable in the url upwards, repeat until the table is empty and then export it as Excel/CSV-Table. I thougt of building that with PHP so we can use it everywhere.

The POST-Login is what I understand how to do. But grabbing the Table could give me some hassle. Do I need to grab everything from  to  and copy that in a Variable like $table and then I need to parse them. Can someone help an PHP noob with that?

The URL to count is something like that: "https://cashier.mysystem.com/compta/bank/search.php?page=5&search_start_dtmonth=10&search_start_dtday=1&search_start_dtyear=2015&search_end_dtmonth=9&search_end_dtday=30&search_end_dtyear=2016&sortfield=b.dateo&sortorder=asc"

The variable to count upwards is "page="

Regards

Comment: As I can see you are describing an algorithm, so, please post some code and we will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap Datatable and its plugins , which are MIT licensed (free) to export that data to CSV file.

for example : buttons.html5.min.js , buttons.print.min.js (google for this JS files)